# How to create a smart contract factory that inherits its token?

Tags: solidity, tokens, factory

For example, here I have two contracts:

- The first one is the smart contract factory that also implements a token.
- The second one is the smart contract model that will be created by the smart contract factory.

So the question is, what should I change in the second smart contract so that I can use the token created in the first smart contract?

My idea is to have a "*country*" (factory) smart contract that creates its own token and also generates other "*city*" contracts. My goal is, for the "city" contracts to be able to buy and sell the tokens created in the "*country*" contract. Here is an example code.

```
import "./ERC20.sol";

contract SmartContract1 {

 ERC20Basic private token;

 constructor () public {
    token = new ERC20Basic(10000);
    owner = msg.sender;
 }

 function Factory() public {
    address new_contract_address = address (new SmartContract2(msg.sender)); 
 }
}

contract SmartContract2 {

 address public owner;

 constructor (address _direccion) public {
    owner = _direccion;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by "use". If you only want to call its functions, you can import the IERC20 interface and call its functions like this:

```
(smartContract1Address).transferFrom(from,to,amount);
```

link:

```
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a modifier to have privilege access to those token contracts. What you need is an interface for it and some functions from the factory contract to manage the state of the children contract.

```
contract Factory {

    event NewToken(address)


    function createToken() returns bool{
        Token token = new Token(address(this))
        emit NewToken(address(token))    
    }
}

contract Token {

    address factory;

    constructor(address _factory){
        factory = _factory;
    }

    modifier isFactory {
        if(msg.sender !== factory){
            revert("Only the factory can access this");
        }
        _;
    }    

}
```